# Android Studio Gradle sets Target API at Android L

Tags: android, api, gradle, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

Not only can you not test your apps without using Android L(which is still not completely refined at all), but you cannot even target API level 19 as it is constantly being overwritten by Gradle. I reported this to Google, but apparently this is intended, yet they don't tell me how to target API 19 (KitKat).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using 20.x libraries in your build.gradle and not 21.x

Comment: They are the 20.x libraries, also tried changed the targetSDKVersion in the build.gradle to 19 instead of "L", but didn't work either.